# Convert RGB values to Integer

Tags: java, bufferedimage

So in a `BufferedImage`, you receive a single integer that has the RGB values represented in it. So far I use the following to get the RGB values from it:

```
// rgbs is an array of integers, every single integer represents the
// RGB values combined in some way
int r = (int) ((Math.pow(256,3) + rgbs[k]) / 65536);
int g = (int) (((Math.pow(256,3) + rgbs[k]) / 256 ) % 256 );
int b = (int) ((Math.pow(256,3) + rgbs[k]) % 256);
```

And so far, it works.

What I need to do is **figure out how to get an integer** so I can use `BufferedImage.setRGB()`, because that takes the same type of data it gave me.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I think the code is something like:

```
int rgb = red;
rgb = (rgb << 8) + green;
rgb = (rgb << 8) + blue;
```

Also, I believe you can get the individual values using:

```
int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
int green = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
int blue = rgb & 0xFF;
```

Comment: I don't think you need an int on the second two lines. And the third line is supposed to be "rgb = ...", right?

Comment: It is a single integer. An integer contains 32 bits. The first 8 bits are for the alpha value (which is zero). The next 8 for the red, then next 8 for the green and the next 8 for the blue. Try it. If the final output equals you initial input then you know the conversion was done correctly.

Comment: Erm, I think it would depend on the color depth. Your example looks like 24-bit color to me (8 bits per channel) - is that what `BufferedImage` expects?

Comment: Yes, I made the assumption the buffered image is of type BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB. Maybe it isn't which is why the other formula is being used. In any case the concept is that (as far as i know) it is easier to shift bits to get the individual values instead of using the code posted.

Comment: what are the values for red, green and blue in your first code sample

Comment: @GoldenLion, they are the individual values between 0-255 for each of your red/green/blue values. In the question r/g/b is used as the variable names.

Comment: def colorValue(value):
    retVal=((value[0]&0x0ff)<<16)|((value[1]&0x0ff)<<8)|(value[2]&0x0ff)
    return retVal   If I pass in (255,120,111) will I get the correct value?

Answer (score 37):

```
int rgb = ((r&0x0ff)<<16)|((g&0x0ff)<<8)|(b&0x0ff);
```

If you know that your r, g, and b values are never > 255 or < 0 you don't need the &0x0ff

Additionaly

```
int red = (rgb>>16)&0x0ff;
int green=(rgb>>8) &0x0ff;
int blue= (rgb)    &0x0ff;
```

No need for multipling.

Answer (score 30):

if r, g, b = 3 integer values from 0 to 255 for each color

then

```
rgb = 65536 * r + 256 * g + b;
```

the single rgb value is the composite value of r,g,b combined for a total of 16777216 possible shades.

Comment: I would modify this to be `rgb = 0xFFFF * r + 0xFF * g + b;` for readability

Comment: 0xFF = 255. Would have to be 0x100. Likewise for 0XFFFF

Comment: Thanks for this simple but elegant formula... saved my day :D

Answer (score 28):

```
int rgb = new Color(r, g, b).getRGB();
```

Answer (score 6):

To get individual colour values you can use Color like following for pixel(x,y).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

Color c = new Color(buffOriginalImage.getRGB(x,y));
int red = c.getRed();
int green = c.getGreen();
int blue = c.getBlue();
```

The above will give you the integer values of Red, Green and Blue in range of 0 to 255.

To set the values from RGB you can do so by:

```
Color myColour = new Color(red, green, blue);
int rgb = myColour.getRGB();

//Change the pixel at (x,y) ti rgb value
image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
```

Please be advised that the above changes the value of a single pixel. So if you need to change the value entire image you may need to iterate over the image using two for loops.