# How to use this Color's constructor? Java

Tags: java, swing, colors, rgb

According to Oracle's site, the class Color has a constructor that accepts a single int value which represents an RGB value. [http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int%29)

An RGB color is actually three different numbers ranging from 0-255. So combining them together to make one int would look like this:

```
White 255,255,255
White 255255255
```

Right? So I pass this to the constructor and get a vibrant teal color. What am I doing wrong? What haven't I understood?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Convert RGB values to Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801366/convert-rgb-values-into-integer-pixel/4801397#4801397)

```
int rgb = red;
rgb = (rgb << 8) + green;
rgb = (rgb << 8) + blue;
```

To pull values out:

```
int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
int green = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
int blue = rgb & 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 2):

Javadoc from the other constructor:

> Creates an sRGB color with the
>   specified combined RGBA value
>   consisting of the alpha component in
>   bits 24-31, the red component in bits
>   16-23, the green component in bits
>   8-15, and the blue component in bits
>   0-7. If the hasalpha argument is
>   false, alpha is defaulted to 255.

So, you just need to construct the int using [bit operations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Color col=new Color(255,255,255);
Label l1=new Label("I got this color");
```

//setting the color in label background

```
l1.setBackground(col);
```