# Storing RGB in an unsigned 16bit integer

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I'm storing a 3 value RGB representation into an 16bit integer by bit shifting it based off an answer from here ([Convert RGB values to Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801366/convert-rgb-values-into-integer-pixel)). It seems to work for the `g` and `b` values, but `r` is always returned as 0.

My code is:

```
uint16_t rgb = ((r&0x0ff) << 16) | ((g&0x0ff) << 8) | (b&0x0ff);
        qDebug() << "wrote rgb: " << rgb;
        qDebug() << "wrote r: " << r << " g: " << g << " b: " << b;
        qDebug() << "unshifted r: " << ((rgb >> 16) & 0x0ff) << " g: " << ((rgb >> 8) & 0x0ff) << " b: " << (rgb & 0x0ff);
```

Comment: You can't put 24 bits of data into a 16 bit variable.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed what I was doing. Which just goes to show you don't notice things until you've posted them on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to store RGB in a 16-bit integer, you can only store the colors with limited resolution. Typically you use 5 bits each for red and blue, and 6 bits for green.

This was once fairly common -- while it does reduce color resolution, the result remains fairly usable for many purposes (business graphics and such, but *not* decent photo editing or anything like that where color accuracy matters).

Comment: Thanks, I posted and then realised what I'd done wrong. I'm going to shift them to 5bit representations as the colour accuracy doesn't need to be 100% exact.

Answer (score 5):

You're using a 16bit int, and shifting your red value by 16 bits, so you're effectively just doing `r = 0`. You're literally shifting your values past the end of the available space. To store three 8 bit values, you need at LEAST 24 bits, meaning you'll have to use a uint32_t instead.

Comment: I have to store them in a uint16_t unfortunately otherwise I would. I'm going to change them into a 5 bit representation instead.