# Creating a pixel given r g b in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Using [imagez](https://github.com/mikera/imagez) I can get a pixel from an image as `[r g b]`. Using this [colour wheel](http://www.colorspire.com/rgb-color-wheel/) I have verified that this extraction part is almost certainly working. This is the imagez code that does the extraction:

```
(defn components-rgb
  "Return the RGB components of a colour value, in a 3-element vector of long values"
  ([^long rgb]
   [(bit-shift-right (bit-and rgb 0x00FF0000) 16)
    (bit-shift-right (bit-and rgb 0x0000FF00) 8)
    (bit-and rgb 0x000000FF)]))
```

I need to do the opposite of this extraction. Here are some examples of the 'colour value' (or pixel) being extracted:

```
First pixel: -6700606 (in HEX: FFFFFFFFFF99C1C2)  
Last pixel: -11449516 (in HEX: FFFFFFFFFF514B54)  
First as colour: [153 193 194] (in HEX: 99 C1 C2)   
Last as colour: [81 75 84] (in HEX: 51 4B 54)
```

Doing the opposite would mean that `[153 193 194]` becomes `-6700606`. This question has been asked before on SO, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801366/convert-rgb-values-into-integer-pixel). Here are two of my attempts which do not work:

```
;rgb = 0xFFFF * r + 0xFF * g + b
(defn my-rgb-1 [[r g b]]
  (+ (* 0xFFFF r) (* 0xFF g) b))  

;int rgb = ((r&0x0ff)<<16)|((g&0x0ff)<<8)|(b&0x0ff);
(defn my-rgb-2 [[r g b]]
(let [red (bit-shift-left 16 (bit-and r 0x0FF))
      green (bit-shift-left 8 (bit-and g 0x0FF))
      blue (bit-and b 0x0FF)]
 (bit-or red green blue)))
```

image --1--> extracted-pixel --2--> rgb colour --3--> to-write-pixel --4--> image

Steps 1 and 2 are working, but step 3 is not. If step 3 were working extracted-pixel would be the same as to-write-pixel.

There is an `rgb` function in imagez, but it too does not work for me. (The author updated me to say it is not supposed to. See [here](https://github.com/mikera/imagez/issues/23)). I might also add that the imagez function `get-pixel` is first used to get the pixel (step 1), followed by `components-rgb` (step 2) as shown above.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/chrismurrph/want-pixel/blob/master/src/my/issue.clj) where I have outlined the steps.

Comment: I suggest you post the hexadecimal representation of the colors instead of the decimal one, it will be more clear for you and for us.

Comment: your `my-rgb-2` attempt: the commented line is a description of what you want? Then you are missing a few `bit-shift-left`s (you do the `bit-and`s and `bit-or`s - but decided to ignore `<<` ?)

Comment: also `(format "0x%x" -6700606) => "0xffffffffff99c1c2"` is possiblty helpful when printing bits/hex

Comment: `There is an rgb function in imagez, but it too does not work for me.` can you clarify this ? [the function](https://github.com/mikera/imagez/blob/develop/src/main/clojure/mikera/image/colours.clj#L15-L24) looks exactly like what you want ?

Comment: https://github.com/chrismurrph/want-pixel/blob/master/src/my/issue.clj clarifies that the existing `rgb` function in imagez does not work for me. Thanks.

Comment: so your problem is that `(in HEX: FFFFFFFFFF99C1C2)` != `(in HEX: 99 C1 C2)` - I give you `unchecked-int` : `(format "0x%x" (unchecked-int 0xFFFFFFFFFF99C1C2)) => 0xff99c1c2` - its the "same", just once `long` and once `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the arguments to bit-shift-left in the wrong order. So this is a basic version of the improved `my-rgb-2`:

```
(defn my-rgb-2 [[r g b]]
  (let [red (bit-shift-left r 16)
        green (bit-shift-left g 8)
        blue b]
    (bit-or red green blue)))
```

I have left off `(bit-and a 0x0FF)`, (where a is r, g or b), simply because it is only necessary if the number is more than 255, which would not be a proper value anyway. For this answer it doesn't really matter whether it is there or not.

The next thing to do is put all the 0xF (all 4 bits filled in) at the beginning. This nearly gets me there:

```
(defn my-rgb-2 [[r g b]]
  (let [red (bit-shift-left (bit-and r 0x0FF) 16)
        green (bit-shift-left (bit-and g 0x0FF) 8)
        blue (bit-and b 0x0FF)]
    (bit-or 0xFFFFFFFFF000000 (bit-or red green blue))))
```

Unfortunately if I put one more 0xF on the last line I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bit operation not supported for: class clojure.lang.BigInt
```

But that can be fixed by borrowing from the answer @birdspider gave:

```
(defn my-rgb-2 [[r g b]]
  (let [red (bit-shift-left (bit-and r 0x0FF) 16)
        green (bit-shift-left (bit-and g 0x0FF) 8)
        blue (bit-and b 0x0FF)]
    (bit-or (bit-or red green blue) (unchecked-int 0xFFFFFFFFFF000000))))
```

The imagez library now has this function, but done as a macro for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your poblem correctly - the issue you have is that:

```
"First pixel" in hex is i.e 0xFFFFFFFFF99C1C2
 you convert it to decimal-rgb via `components-rgb` = [153 193 194]
 you re-convert [153 193 194] to int via `rbg` and get 
  0x99C1C2
which by all means is correct
```

since clojure by default uses long the only thing you need to do 
is use a `unchecked-int` to trucate the `long` to `int` as so:

```
(unchecked-int 0xFFFFFFFFFF99C1C2)
-6700606
```

which is what you want - right ?

Comment: Looking at issue.clj you can use any of `existing-rgb`, `my-rgb-1` or `my-rgb-2`. Last time I looked none of them returned the right answer.